# How to give a function to an image while in a website

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a button that makes an image appear on a website when you click it. I want to make that image delete itself when its clicked. Is there any way I can do that? I tried:

```
function show_image(onclick) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.onclick = onclick;
}

show_image('delete()');

function delete() {
  style.display = 'none';
}
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: Delete itself, or disappear?

Comment: I want it to delete itself

Comment: so why is your pseudo code just hiding it?

Comment: because display none is pretty close to deleting it

Answer (score 3):

You can use `node.remove`:

```js
let img = document.getElementById("img");
img.onclick = () => img.remove();
```

```html
<img src="img.jpg" id="img">
```

Comment: yea this would work but the image that I want to delete creates itself in the website not in the code, and I dont know how to give it an id in the website

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const img = document.querySelector('img')
    document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {
      img.style.display = 'block'
    }
    document.querySelector('img').onclick = () => {
      img.style.display = 'none'
    }
```

```html
<button> show img </button>
<img src='./border.png' />
```